# Show that $a \equiv b \pmod {p^k} \implies a^p \equiv b^p \pmod{p^{k+1}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime.

Show that $a \equiv b \pmod {p^k} \implies a^p \equiv b^p \pmod{p^{k+1}}$

$(a-b)(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}) \equiv 0.pa^{p-1}=0 \pmod{p^k}$

How do I get $\pmod{p^{k+1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

$$a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1} \equiv p \times a^{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

and $$x \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}, y \equiv 0 \pmod p \Rightarrow xy \equiv 0 \pmod  {p^{k+1}}$$

Comment: I do not understand your last bit

Comment: Since $a^p-b^p \equiv (a-b)(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}) $ and $a-b$ is divisible by $p^k$ and  $a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}$ is divisble by $p$ , as shown in my first statement. Thus $a-b$ is of the form $p^km$ and $a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}$ is of the form $pn$. Thus $a^p-b^p$ is of the form $p^{k+1}mn$, thus implying $a^p-b^p$ is divisible by $p^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have $a=b+qp^k$ for some integer $q$. Take the $p$-th power of both sides, using the binomial theorem.

We get 
$$a^p=b^p+pb^{p-1}qp^k+\text{terms that involve powers of $p$ $\ge p^{k+1}$}.$$

Comment: How do I know that $p^{k(p-1)} \geq p^{k+1}$

Comment: The second term is clearly divisible by $p^{k+1}$. The next term after that involves $p^{2k}$, and $2k\ge k+1$. The next term after that involves $p^{3k}$, and $3k\ge k+1$, and so on.